# JSON server: & and |

Tags: json, json-server

Titles for query: ["title1", "title2", "title3 & title3]

Request for json server looks this way: ?title1 | title2 | title3&title3

And this works until order is changed: title3&title3|title1|title2

(this query ingore everything after ampersand symbol)

***The question***: is there way to say to `json server`, that ampersand is not a part of regular expression? And get objects for all three titles without changing order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

> If you want to use an ampersand as a value inside the query string of
> a url (and not as a delimiter for separating arguments), then you
> should use the URL-encoded value: %26